Can I safely remove fwupd* packages from Linux Mint 21.3 desktop?
# apt-get --simulate remove 'fwupd*'

...

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin5
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fwupd fwupd-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv fwupd [1.7.9-1~22.04.3]
Remv fwupd-signed [1.51.1~22.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1]

It appears harmless to remove, but I am unsure if e.g. the OS needs it for something?

For completeness, I attach the output of refresh command:
# fwupdmgr refresh

WARNING: UEFI capsule updates not available or enabled in firmware setup
  See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:capsules-unsupported for more information.
Updating lvfs
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Nothing depends on those packages, so removing them won’t break anything. fwupd is used for firmware updates, so all you lose by removing it is the ability to use it for firmware updates. Your system doesn’t support UEFI capsule updates anyway, so it’s likely that you couldn‘t use fwupd to update your main firmware.
fwupd can also update some peripherals’ firmware, so you might want to keep it for that. Examples include Logitech receivers and some keyboards.
